# Force SSL for Django Postgres connection

Tags: django, postgresql

I want to force Django to use SSL to connect to my postgres database.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28228241/2800876) indicates that I need to pass `sslmode='require'` to the psycopg2 connect call.  How do I add this to Django's database paremeters?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Add `'OPTIONS': {'sslmode': 'require'},` to your database config.  For example:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': "db_name",
        'USER': "db_username",
        'PASSWORD': "db_password",
        'HOST': "db_host",
        'OPTIONS': {'sslmode': 'require'},
    },
}
```

As [jklingen92 points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62962132/2800876), if you are using a database URL, such as through [django-environ](https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), add `?sslmode=require` to the end of your database URL.  For example:

```
postgres://<DB_USERNAME>:<DB_PASSWORD>@<DB_HOST>:<PORT>/<DB_NAME>?sslmode=require
```

Comment: Are you not supposed to pass a certificat ?

Comment: @Florent The database client doesn't need to specify a certificate unless you're using the optional clientcert authentication options.  How to do that in Django is a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35869001/2800876)

Answer (score 9):

If you're configuring a database URL, you can pass options as query parameters:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/NAME?sslmode=require
```

This works with both [Django Configurations](https://django-configurations.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and with [Django Environ](https://django-environ.readthedocs.org/).
Django Configurations is built off of `dj_database_url`, so you can also pass `ssl_require=True` as @frmdstryr said:

```
DATABASES = values.DatabaseURLValue(environ_required=True, ssl_require=True)
```

Comment: where to specify the certificate ?

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal You can specify paths to SSL certificate by adding the following to OPTIONS (along the aforementioned sslmode attribute): 
           { 'sslmode': 'require',
            'sslcert': '/path/to/file',
            'sslkey': '/path/to/file',
            'sslrootcert': '/path/to/file'}

Answer (score 4):

If you're using [dj_database_url](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url) you can pass `ssl_require=True` which sets the option for you.

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(ssl_require=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `settings.py` file like this:

```py
DATABASES = {
    # 'default': {
    #     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    #     'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    # },
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'HOST': 'server-ip',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'NAME': 'database-name',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'sslmode': 'require',
            'sslcert': '/path/to/file',
            'sslkey': '/path/to/file',
            'sslrootcert': '/path/to/file',
        },
    },
}
```

references  [visit here](https://neoctobers.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/django_postgresql.html)