# Django - postgres: how can I verify whether the database connection is SSL?

Tags: django, postgresql, ssl

My postgres server should be forcing SSL connection however I would like to verify this setting directly from the Django app. Is there a  way to inspect the database connection (perhaps through `manage.py shell` and make sure the connection is SSL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can confirm that the connection is encrypted by looking for the cipher in the connection information after navigating to `python manage.py dbshell`

```
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, bits: 
128, compression: off)
```

otherwise, you will see no SSL information.

Comment: awesome. Elegant and easy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to configure that from your Django app, but maybe you could tell postgres to [require SSL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-connect.html) in the `sslmode` connection parameter?

Comment: yes that can be configured in the Django DATABASES setting ([answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47683059/force-ssl-for-django-postgres-connection)). However, that doesn't really tell me if my existing connection is SSL (such as if I have a DB-server-enforced SSL without configuring SSL in Django). However, I think I found a way to do it and I will post.

Comment: @JadS Ok, as I understand it, your solution actually lets you verify if it is using SSL, but it requires a module. IMHO, if you tell your postgres driver that you require SSL, wouldn't it be a bug if it allowed you connect without SSL? Also, this post now links to https://stackoverflow.com/a/47683060/3914029 which tells you specifically how to set that parameter for your Django app. However, I'd mark your answer as solution, as it is what you actually wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found one way, but I will wait before accepting in case people have critiques of this method:

1. connect to the database server as superuser and run `create extension sslinfo;` to install the sslinfo extension. This may not be possible for some who don't have superuser access, however in my case where I configured server-side SSL enforcement, SU access is given.
2. run the following in `manage.py shell`:

-

```
from django.db import connection

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute('select ssl_is_used();')
    output = cursor.fetchall()
    print(output) # will print [(True,)] if SSL
```

This executes raw SQL which should return [(True,)] if SSL is enabled.

Relevant [documentation about sslinfo can be found here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sslinfo.html)